# Get TestCategory from inside test class init

Tags: unit-testing, moq

In Visual Studio one can mark Unit test methods with an attribute like this

```
[TestCategory("moq"), TestCategory("NominalIntegration")]
```

The above would let Visual Studio list this test class in the Test Explorer, showing this test under the "moq" trait, and the "NominalIntegration" trait.  I'd like to group by Trait.

What I'd like to do is have a block of code in my class init method so that if I run the moq trait, then my moq objects are used, otherwise the real objects are used.
Something like

```
[ClassInitialize()] 
public static void ClassInit(TestContext context)
{
 if ( I_ran_the_tests_by_clicking_on_the_group_moq_trait){
     dependancyMoq = new Mock<myInterface>();
      //define dependancyMoq.Setup for general conditions
     myClassUnderTest = new ClassUnderTest ( dependancyMoq.Object);   
}
else 
    myClassUnderTest = new ClassUnderTest ( );
```

}

so that I could run a number of the same tests with a dummy or not, and by simply choosing a test group with a different trait. Even if this block is in test initialize instead, how do I get the current running trait?

Comment: You do not. The `ClassInitialize` runs before the context of the `TestMethod` activates. In `TestInitialize` you might be able to access it through the `TestContext` property, but I'm not 100% sure.